# JSON Parse xmlhttp.requestText

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, auto-populate

I have a form that has a **dynamic drop down select** that when a value is selected it **auto populates** two other form fields, short and long description. I am trying to use **Ajax** to retrieve the short and long desc based on the value of the drop down select. I can receive the **xmlhttp.responseText** data and display it back on the form page but I am unable to **parse** the responseText out to the respective form fields.

You can see the responseText displayed above "Add New Record" title. It might be hard to read so here it is again: (I was thinking I might have the wrong format)

```
{"Stitl":"CHF STAFF","Ltitl":"Chief Of Staff"}
```

[image]

HTML file:

```
<form id="addForm" method="post"  action="units_add.php">

 <legend>Add New Record</legend>
     <label for="titleOrg" class="control-label">Title Org</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="titleOrg" id="titleOrg" onChange="populate(this.value)">
               <option value=" "></option>
               <?php
                  while ($rowl1l5s = $l1l5Result->fetch_assoc()) {
                       echo "<option value=". $rowl1l5s['l1l5']. ">";
                       echo $rowl1l5s['l1l5'] . "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" .$rowl1l5s['Ltitl']; ;
                       echo "</option>";
                  }?>
          </select>

     <label for="shortDesc" class="control-label">Short Desc</label>
          <input name="shortDesc" class="form-control" id="shortDesc" type="text" readonly="readonly">

     <label for="longDesc" class="control-label">Long Desc</label>
          <input name="longDesc" class="form-control" id="longDesc" type="text" readonly="readonly">

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="save"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-white"></i> Save</button>

     <a href="FDMAMaint_V10.php"
          <button class="btn btn-default"  id="cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
    </a>
</form>
```

Then the user selects a value from the dynamic drop down it executes this JS function:

```
function populate(str)
{
     if (str=="")
     {
          document.getElementById("shortDesc").innerHTML="";
          return;

      }

      // Create an object 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }

      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }


      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {

          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {

              data = xmlhttp.responseText;

              document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              document.getElementById("shortDesc").value=xmlhttp.responseText.shortDesc
              document.getElementById("longDesc").value=xmlhttp.responseText.second;

          }
       }
              xmlhttp.open("GET","getl2l5.php?q="+str,true);
              xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

I know that the following code (see below) doesn't work because it's being referenced wrong, plus it hasn't been parsed yet. I was just throwing that in there for reference as to why the form fields are "undefined"

```
document.getElementById("shortDesc").value=xmlhttp.responseText.shortDesc
document.getElementById("longDesc").value=xmlhttp.responseText.second;
```

Then the JS function goes out to the getL2L5 PHP script:

```
<?php

    define('DBHOST','**************');
    define('DBUSER','********');
    define('DBPASS','**********');
    define('DBNAME','**********');

    //Connect to database
    if (!$db = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME)) die("Can't connect to database");

    // Retrieve the value from the title org drop down select 
    $q = $_GET['q']; 

    // Pull the Ltitl and Stitl based on the drop down value
    $sql="SELECT Stitl, Ltitl FROM tl2l5 WHERE l1l5= '".$q."'";

    // Execute the query 
    if (!$result = $db->query($sql))
    {
            die("There was an error running the query [" .$db->error. "]");
    }

    $data = array();
    // Step through the query result and fetch the values
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $Stitl = $row['Stitl'];
            $Ltitl = $row['Ltitl'];
            $data = array( 'Stitl' => $Stitl, 'Ltitl' => $Ltitl);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
Thank you `@TimSPQR` for the JSFiddle. This helped me get on the right track. I realized my issue was of my own doing. I used your JSFiddle to alert the value of `var mydata` and it displayed this:

[image]

then I went to my code to alert my variable and got this:

[image]

**SOLUTION:** Once I marked the html comments as php comments I was able to use JSON.parse on the xmlhttp.responseText and populate the two form fields referencing their correct field titles (ex: data.Stitl)

Comment: Why are you treating `xmlhttp.responseText` as if it's an object? It's just a string. Also, if your problem is PHP and JavaScript, it usually isn't: either the JavaScript is broken, and then PHP is irrelevant, or the JS works fine, and it's a PHP problem with irrelevant JS. Treat any "PHP + JS" problem as two possible problems, and debug accordingly.

Comment: I'm able to get the data and it comes back in this format `{"Stitl":"CHF STAFF","Ltitl":"Chief Of Staff"}` but I don't understand how to reference the Stitl/Ltitl values to display in the input form fields. My JS/PHP is working fine I just was wanting to know how to parse out the values.

Comment: Then I must question whether you googled for this, because "javascript parse JSON" will pretty much be pages and pages of results that tell you to use `JSON.parse`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: This fiddle may get you started - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/c1a82wop/

Comment: Is  there really that much content in short/long descriptions to where you don't just preload all that data into a javascript object on page load (or on first dropdown change event)? Why have AJAX call every time to retrieve two relatively short strings?

Comment: @MikeBrant I am new to all of this so I didn't know of any other way to do it besides through Ajax but I appreciate the suggestion. I will look into it as an alternative! Thanks!